# parallel output using mpi4py in ascii format

Tags: python, output, ascii, mpi4py

All,

I am searching through the documentation of the mpi4py library but important details seem to be left out.
Below is a short python script for writing parallel output to a file. 
The first question is: the output must be written in *ascii format*, so how does one do that exactly ? Secondly, the output can consist of a mixture of integers, floats and strings, so the buffer will need to be defined accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

amode = MPI.MODE_WRONLY|MPI.MODE_CREATE
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
fh = MPI.File.Open(comm, "test.dat", amode)
buffer = np.empty(10, dtype=np.int)
buffer[:] = comm.Get_rank()
print(buffer)
offset = comm.Get_rank() * buffer.nbytes
print(offset)
fh.Write_at_all(offset, buffer)
fh.Close()
```